# Best practices, How to specify relative path for css,javascript and images files?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, image

I have a question about relative path to external javascript, css and images files in Asp.C# application.

I have pages with 2 - 5 sub levels so my javascript and css files looks like

```
../../../../../javascriptfile.js
../../../cssfile.css
../../../../../../image.jpg
```

In case if it will be additional sub level application won't find files.

What is the best practices  to specify path to file???

Comment: the answer will be just to reorganize the files to reduce the usage of such relative path :)

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind when considering these answers that "root-relative" and "root of the site" may really mean the root of the path following the domain name in the url.  You may need to take into account scenarios where your web site is not located at the root.  In such scenarios, root-relative paths would potentially point to a different web site.

In ASP.NET you can use a leading ~ to generate urls relative to the root of current site for most server-side controls, as in:
`<img src="~/image.jpg" runat="server">`

You can also use the [ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method (and other similar methods) to expand such paths without using server-side controls.

Comment: This has the added bonus of working wonderfully in master pages, and more consistently with advanced routing techniques.  Keep in mind that the same page (or masterpage) may be referred to from different paths within your application.

Answer (score 1):

Use a root-relative path like this:

```
    /js/javascriptfile.js
    /css/style.css
```

the first / means at the root of the site.

Comment: I generally avoid referencing scripts like this to avoid virtual path issues.  This works if you're sure your project will always be hosted out of the root of the web server, but I know personally that is rarely if ever the case.  The ResolveUrl tip above is a much safer bet.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute or root-relative paths to avoid confusion in multi-level pages.

Look here for more information:
http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php