# asp.net, how to serve static files

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie to ASP.net and just can't find any documentation on how to serve static files on ASP.NET. I'm referring to files such as images/javascripts/jars/xls, etc...

To be a little clearer, I am not interested in serving files to the user, but rather to my javascripts, java applets, etc... So what I am looking for is a way to have handle specific GET requests with argument are return the files with appropriate MIME type.

Do you have any suggestions on the different ways to do this ? 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute or root-relative paths to avoid confusion in multi-level pages

in ASP.NET you can use a leading ~ to generate urls relative to the root of current site for most server-side controls, as in: `<img src="~/image.jpg" runat="server">`

You can also use the `ResolveUrl` method (and other similar methods) to expand such paths without using server-side controls.

If you need to use those paths within your JS code you can do the below:

```
var JQueryPath=<%= Url.Content ("~/Img/myImage.jpg") %>"
```

for more info :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx

[Best practices, How to specify relative path for css,javascript and images files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211976/best-practices-how-to-specify-relative-path-for-css-javascript-and-images-files)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an ASP .NET issue, and more a job for IIS.

Don't make the mistake of assuming that you need to do everything with server controls.  If you just want people to be able to download these files, a simple `<a href='/yourstaticcontent'>link</a>` will do, and is actually preferable to using a server-side control.

**EDIT**
I agree with Massimiliano on expressing paths from the root.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear I think, I update the question. I am not interested in serving files for the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed IIS/ASP.NET from the Control Panel, you might not have turned on static Content.

You'll find a checkbox for it in the Control Panel, Turn Windows Features On or Off: World Wide Web Services/Common HTTP Features/Static Content